# Assumptions for nlme

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, assumptions, lme4-nlme

I want to analyze a repeated measure design with two independent variables (`var1`, `var2`) where the subjects had to solve three tasks in a row (the repeated factor - `var3`). I build my model with the `lme` function from the `nlme`-package as

```
lme(depvar ~ ..., random = ~1|userid/var3, data=my.data, method="ML")
```

where `...` stands for the full model of all three variables with all possible interactions. I was looking in the book by A. Field, and Googled around quite a bit, but I could not find a worked out example that tells me what assumptions I should check beforehand.

In addition, since I consider many different dependent variables it would be nice to be able to test the assumptions automatically. The only thing I found so far is about qq-plots which I would have to check by myself. I have basically two questions:

1. Which assumptions do I have to check and do I have to do this groupwise with respect to `var1`, `var2` and `var3`?
2. Is there a way to do the tests none graphically like the normality assumption of an ANOVA?

It would be great if you had some suggestions and references.

Comment: What is "the book by A. Field"? I'm not familiar with it & I didn't find anything by Googling.

Comment: "Discovering statistics using R" (or very similar) by Andy Field.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the omission - the title is indeed "Discovering Statistics using R" and the authors are Andy Field, Jeremy Miles and Zoe Field.